# CSS: force newline for elements to stay together

Tags: css

I have two elements that must stay next to each other (input and button). If the previous text becomes too long then they must BOTH be pushed to the next line. However, they should not be pushed to the next line if they can both fit on the first line.

```
<div>
    tag: some words of
    <span>We must stay </span><span>together</span>
</div>
```

Edit: updated fiddle to also show desired result (although it uses br, which answer should not)

http://jsfiddle.net/GSf67/5/

Edit: clarification The width of the parent must not extend beyond its specified width. Instead, a newline should be forced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wrapping them in a `div` styled with `display:inline-block`:

```
<div class="container">
    tag: some words of
    <div style="display:inline-block">
        <span>We must stay </span><span>together</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Yet another fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HsZRB/

Comment: That did it! Also in my real life css.

Answer (score 0):

Forking your Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7pB2q/

You want to add the following to your `div` selector:

```
div {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: The width of the parent must not extend beyond its specified width. Instead, a newline should be forced.